# How to create an AP with belkin usb using rtl8192u?

Tags: wifi, usb, wifi-hotspot

As I can remember, once I have seen it working, but it was not today. Can I do something to use it as an AP?

Comment: what is a "belkin USB"?

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done, it may not be as stable or reliable as you would like due to issues with the age of the driver which I discuss below.

The driver is unmaintained, and broken as reported by [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.7-Staging).  Quoting:

> The other driver being removed is the rtl8192u WiFi driver that's been in staging. It turns out that this driver has been broken since 2016 without anyone stepping up to address the quality of this driver and apparently not much usage by Linux users. This driver is for the RealTek RTL8192U Wireless LAN NICs

Encryption requires Firmware, and the most recent firmware I could find searching old forum posts is about 13 years old and last reliably worked in the 2.6.x kernel.  I'm saying this because although the [2.6 kernel is still available](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/), attempting to upgrade to mainline kernels will further inhibit proper operation of the very old driver.